# Direct decomposition of vector space in image of map plus kernel of adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $A:V\to W$ be a linear map with $V,W$ finite dimensional Hilbert spaces. Is it always true that 
$$ \dim(\mathrm{Im}(A)) + \dim(\ker(A^*)) = \dim(W),$$

i.e. (since $\mathrm{Im}(A) \cap \ker(A^*) = 0$) 
$$W = \mathrm{Im}(A) \oplus \ker (A^*)?$$

Notation: $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$, $\mathrm{Im}$ and $\ker$ stand for Image and Kernel.

I have something like this in mind, but don't find it in my linear algebra notes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the obvious fact that $\ker A^*=(\mathrm{Im}\ A)^{\perp}$. Now it remains to show that $W=\mathrm{Im}\ A\oplus(\mathrm{Im}\ A)^{\perp}$. But this follows from the definition of the orthogonal complement.